# Does IE-Only attributes works while Developer Tools open?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, frontend, developer-tools

I'm trying to test a website on **IE8**, While i don't have **IE8** on my computer i use **Developer tools (f12)** and **document mode** to imitate **IE8**, But it doesn't work, The browser isn't loading the alternative CSS file.

Comment: Can you please post *small* sample of what you trying to test? It is not clear how "attributes" and CSS are related.

Comment: <!--[if lt IE 8]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

Comment: So what is your question than? Why IE8 does not load CSS for IE7 and below?

Comment: Does imitating IE8 document mode (f12) in Internet Explorer will work in this case of using those "IF IE" statements. That's the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional comments do not work in IE 11, even when using compatibility mode. If you need to test CSS for outdated versions of IE you really need to download a free VM from http://modern.ie. There are 90 to choose from so there should be one you can run locally or in the cloud.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments you specify that you have the following conditional CSS:

`<!--[if lt IE 8]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" /> <![endif]-->`

If this is your actual line, then it's normal your CSS is not loaded, since it's specific for any version below IE8.

IE should load the appropriate styles when you set the document mode.

Answer (score 1):

The Developer tools aren't the best to test websites, because the developer toolbar imitates the wanted, but uses its own agent & JS to make the pages work.

For me the solution is to setup some VM's (virtual machines http://www.vmware.com/eu/) for each browser, to be sure to have the wanted browser in real behaviour, or use something like http://www.browserstack.com/

But, I agree that debugging JS in a IE7 is quite harmful without any tools, I tried many of them, but none to advice! So conclusion, VM's

Also, in IE8 it's the same problem: The toolbar is much better than in IE7 but it's stil not made for developers...

Comment: not sure what you mean by uses its own JS to make pages work. IE ships with the engines for the other browsers and it uses them when in compatibility mode. There are some edge differences, but in general it is the same rendering and JS engines.